# Is it possible to create a complete DOS application to run in window 7 and 8

Tags: c++, c, dos

Is it possible to create a complete MS DOS application to run in windows 7 and windows 8. I like to create a basic accounting application for personal use.

Comment: First thing to pop up on a Google search... [How to run DOS programs in a current version of Windows](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2142380/run-dos-programs-in-a-current-version-of-windows.html)

Comment: Do you want to run an actual MS-DOS program that would work on a old PC running MS-DOS and not Windows? Or do you just want to run a program that would run inside Windows command prompt window?

Comment: i don't want to run the application, i just want to know is it possible to create an application like those we used to use in windows 98.

Comment: I'm asking about the application you want to create. Does it need to be an MS-DOS application, and if so why? You can create Windows console applications that run inside Windows command prompt window.

Comment: Do you actually want a 16-bit application (which then can not run on 64-bit windows)? Or just a text-mode application that runs in a command-shell? Those are distinctly different choices in terms of what compiler you need...

Comment: this has nothing to do with c++...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to create MS-DOS applications on 32-bit versions of Windows. You need a compiler targeting MS-DOS, such as [djgpp](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) (MS-DOS port of gcc) or [Turbo C++](http://web.archive.org/web/20050204085204/http://bdn.borland.com/museum).

It is not possible to run (and thus, develop) MS-DOS applications on 64-bit versions on Windows.

MS-DOS is outdated and it's probably not good idea to write MS-DOS software today. However, Windows applications don't have to be graphical. It's possible to write command line applications for Windows, that run in command prompt. Many people make false assumption that text-mode applications have to be MS-DOS applications.

Answer (score 0):

To compile MS DOS software on Windows 7 or 8, you have to use a [cross compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).